# CQErl - dump data into Cassandra map

Tags: erlang

I am using CqErl to connect to cassandra. My Cassandra schema includes couple of strings data and a map data . This data is unknown in length. How I can insert/dump into map using Cqerl.
At the moment in CQerl, there is no way to insert into map data type of Cassandra.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.